# How do I match the height of both column in a two column layout?

Tags: css, layout, web

I'm currently stuck on an design issue that has had me scratching my head for a bit too long.

I have a two-column layout with one column for content (left) and a side bar that lists some sports venues (right) and this column's content exceeds that of the content column.

Basically what I'm looking to achieve is to make the content column match the left hand column.

Much like the one I quickly did up over on Codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iLJAe
Any advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanking you in advance

Stu :)

Here what I have in my style.css for the two columns.

**style.css**

```
.content {
    border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    float: left;
    margin: 5em 0 0;
    padding: 1em;
    height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
    border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    float: left;
    margin: 5em -0.1em 0;
    padding: 1em;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: First you have to define a width, second, for height 100% you also have to define all of his parents to height 100% (including body and html tag).

http://jsfiddle.net/gomflo/L3cUX/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css `display: table;` property.

First put the two divs in a wrapper (act as a parent div for both)

Like:

```
<div id="#wrapper">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

Then in your css, use `display: table` to the wrapper div and `display:table-cell;` to the column divs (this will make the both divs behave like `<td>` in a table) to get them to same height.

Like:

```
.wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    float:left;
}

.content {
    border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    margin: 5em 0 0;
    padding: 1em;
    height: 100%;
    background: red; /* for test */
    display: table-cell;
}

.sidebar {
    border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    margin: 5em -0.1em 0;
    padding: 1em;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue; /* for test */
    display: table-cell;
}
```

**[WORKING SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CgU42/)**

Comment: Thanks Froient! That is exactly what I'm after :D I do have one quick question, is utilizing the `display: table` and `display: table-cell` old fashioned or is this a current method? I'm asking this more so for the sake cross-browser functionality.

Comment: Yes, it widely used that way or for that kind of layout cases. Unless you are worried about old IEs like 5.5 or IE 6.

Comment: Cheers for that. Just wanted to make sure. I'm not fused about older IE users.