# How do i create a two column content that i can copy only one side?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I have a web page with the content side-by-side, let's say the text like this: http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur167.html

I'd like to be able to select 'n' copy only right paragraphs or left paragraphs. Namely, if I need to copy some Hebrew text I'd like to highlight what I need and ctrl+c only that.

At the same time, the heights of the paragraphs must be equal.

So, let's say, if I have a small Hebrew sentence that translates into a bit longer English text, the next paragraphs must be side-by-side, and not shifted.

UPDATE I've found this answer very helpful for the second issue, but still it doesn't let me copy only selected columns: [How do I match the height of both column in a two column layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751091/how-do-i-match-the-height-of-both-column-in-a-two-column-layout)

Comment: I see 2 ways, both using script, where you either line up the paragraphs using a simple left and right aligned div, or, using a table, make the left cells un-selectable when clicking mouse down in the right cells or vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll definitely need two separate divs, so that the page knows that the two sections of text are separate. If you made two columns, the highlighting would let you highlight everything in the same div.

To align paragraphs you'll need to use some JS to change the position of the paragraphs as you go. This snippet works by giving paragraphs that should be aligned a matching class like 'par-1' and so on.

```js
$(document).on('ready',resizeText);
$(window).on('resize',resizeText);

function resizeText(){
    var prevBottom = 20;
    var numParagraphs = 3;
    for(var index = 1; index<=numParagraphs; index++){
        var start = prevBottom;
        var pars = $('.par-'+index);
        pars.each(function(){
            $(this).css({top:start});
            prevBottom = Math.max(prevBottom,$(this).position().top+$(this).outerHeight(true));
        });
    }
}
```

```css
.row{
 display: flex;
}
.col{
 width:50%;
}
.par{
 position: absolute;
 width:45%;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test Site</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><p class="par-1 par">111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 </p><p class="par-2 par">english text that goes</p><p class="par-3 par">third english line</p></div>
    <div class="col"><p class="par-1 par">hebrew text</p><p class="par-2 par">hebrew line 2</p><p class="par-3 par">third hebrew line</p></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, thanx mate, it works ok with the small text, as required.
But on the other hand, take a look at this jsfiddle sample of this code:
https://jsfiddle.net/mc3bdj59/

Comment: You're right. I didn't think about longer paragraphs. I updated it with some JS to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

This may look a bit silly, and quite frankly I could be way offside here(I'm just a puppy still), but if having the need to highlight only a specific portion of one side or the other, could you not have one side in a overflow content box? ie.

```
.content-left {overflow:scroll}
```

I think that might be a start?

Good luck!

Comment: could you jsfiddle what you mean, please?